# Can I randomly eliminate survey respondents belonging to a severely over-represented group in order to allow for better weighting of data?

Tags: sample, weights

I have a population made of the following segments:
A: 19%
B: 52%
**C: 2%**
D: 10%
E: 17%
F: 0.5%

My final sample (n=1,272), due to a much higher response rate for group C, is
A: 27%
B: 15%
**C: 38%**
D: 9%
E: 7%
F: 4%

By simply weighting the sample data using the population weights, I would have to "overweight" group B more than 3 times, and significantly underweight group C, so violating several weighting best practices.

I was considering to reduce my sample from 1,272 to ~770 by randomly removing members of Group C. This  way I would still have to weight the data, but the weight would be within the rules of thumb: I would not overweight any group more than 2 times and no group would be underweighted to less than 0.3 (I know that the rule of thumb is 0.5).

**Question:** is randomly removing members of Group C methodologically acceptable? Alternatively, how best to correct for the outsized over-representation in the final sample of group **C**?

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of analysis do you intend to perform with the data?  That matters--although, as a general proposition, randomly removing data *always* loses information.

Comment: Thanks Whuber. I am running only descriptive statistics at "overall" level, such as awareness about Brand X, use of Brand X. For specific between groups comparisons, I am using the full dataset, but for "overall" results, I must weight the data because group C, that is very overrepresented, has a very specific behavior, so it would bias the "overall" results.

Comment: This is still not very clear: What do "between groups comparisons" and "overall results" mean? What are those "descriptive statistics"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you probably can randomly remove respondents but I don't think it actually helps anything.

As a thought experiment, let's take the idea to the extreme. You could fully resample your dataset from the available data. That is, you could pick a sample size, say 2000, and randomly select a number of respondents for each group in proportion the population frequency. For example, you would draw 380 (=2000 * 19%) respondents from group A and 1 (=2000 * 0.5%) respondent from group F. That may well be more respondents from group A than you have data for, so you would be repeating some samples.

Then you could proceed with your statistics without any weighting at all.

You might be concerned that the random numbers you used for your random resampling are arbitrary, so perhaps you do the same process multiple times hoping to converge on some average answer.

Now you have two ways of calculating each statistic:
(a) Don't do any resampling, just calculate the statistic directly from the sample using weights
(b) Fully resample multiple times and calculate a running average of the statistic

(a) gives you a single number while (b) gives you a sequence of estimates. The question is, does (b) converge to (a)? If it doesn't, I would suggest that there is a problem. What exactly is (b) converging to? If (b) does converge to (a), that is good, but the calculation of (b) is pointless because you already know what it is going to converge to.

Your approach of partially resampling one group is a mix between (a) and (b) but I think the point still holds. Either it gives you the same result as the the full weighted sample or it doesn't. If it does, that's fine but the calculation was unnecessary. If it doesn't, it's not clear what exactly you have calculated and what it means.

To answer your questions directly:

> Is randomly removing members of Group C methodologically acceptable?

Yes, but it doesn't actually help you so I recommend that you don't

> Alternatively, how best to correct for the outsized over-representation in the final sample of group C?

By simply weighting the sample as you originally did

I think that I am a lot more relaxed about heavy re-weighting (particularly under-weighting) than you are. You refer to some "weighting best practices". Perhaps you could provide a link to those and we could examine what problems the rule of thumb is trying to avoid?

Comment: Thanks a lot Jamie! I'm probably a bit more conservative than you, but I’m also not as concerned with underweighting as I am with overweighting. Without cutting the sample size, I would have had to over-weight some groups fivefold. I was not comfortable assuming that 1 answer should be treated as 5. I don’t always weight the data, but in this instance, statistics regarding awareness of some features and brands varied a lot between segments. Because aggregate statistics were more important than segment level statistics, I felt I had to weight the data.

Comment: Where did I get the rules of thumb:
Van den Bulck, Hilde, et al., eds. The Palgrave handbook of methods for media policy research. London: Palgrave Macmillan, 2019, p. 337
OECD, PISA 2018 tech report: https://www.oecd.org/pisa/data/pisa2018technicalreport/PISA2018%20TecReport-Ch-08-Survey-Weights.pdf
Commercial resources: https://www.decisionanalyst.com/blog/dataweighting/#:~:text=A%20general%20rule%20of%20thumb,data%20(weight%20%E2%80%B9%201.0).

Comment: I don't have enough info to comment on whether you should be weighting or not, so let's assume that you do need to. I keep coming back to the idea that cutting the sample size is basically the same as re-weighting -- rather than re-weighting each member of group C down, you are re-weighting some to down zero and then the remaining down a bit. But you are still effectively up-weighting the other groups.

Comment: The blog post that you reference points out the a major concern is increasing the variance of the estimator. It seems to me that the best approach here is collecting more data and, if that is not possible, re-weighting and computing (and reporting) the variances of the estimators you compute.